# adding item to array in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I know this code is correct, I did not write it.  I am trying to understand what the code is doing.

1. create variable
2. loop through unordered list's children
3. set cssClass = class name
4. if the cssClass is not in myarray, add it to myarray

I am familiar with other ways to check to see if an item is in an array, and familiar with other ways to add an item to an array, but this method confuses me.  Do other languages support this type of syntax?

```
    var myarray = [];
    $(".somelist > li").each(function() {
    var cssClass = $(this).attr("class");

    //This part below is CONFUSING
    if(!myarray[cssClass]) {
         myarray[cssClass] = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: `myarray = []` should be `myarray = {}` if any of the class names are non-integers.

Comment: The conusing and stupid bit is that `myarray` is an array instead of an object. Of course arrays are also objects, it's just not used as an array

Comment: This link may be helpful to others.  http://www.javascriptkata.com/2007/03/29/how-to-use-javascript-hashes/

Comment: another link http://blog.persistent.info/2004/08/javascript-associative-arrays.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1 if(!myarray[cssClass]) {
2         myarray[cssClass] = true;
    }
```

Here's a brief outline of what's happening, the `myarray` variable is used as a hash -

1 - Checks to see if the current class name is in the array. `myarray[cssClass]` will return a '[falsy](http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript)' value if the class name is not conatined in the array.

2 - If the class is not in the array, add it to the array and set it's value to true

Answer (score 2):

If the hash/map doesn't contain an entry for the given class, add it.

It's creating a collection of all the classes used by list items in the somelist class.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it will be false only if it's first occurence of that array. When it's second loop and class is the same, it won't change it to `true` again. It makes no sense though. This code is synonym of

```
    var myarray = [];
    $(".somelist > li").each(function() {
    var cssClass = $(this).attr("class");
    myarray[cssClass] = true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If the array does not contain an entry with the key represented by the cssClass variable it will add it and set the value of that key to true. If it already exists, it stays true...so

```
if(!myarray[cssClass]))
```

returns false if there is no key with the value that is set to the cssClass variable.
I don't know the context of this code but from this point it seems a bit useless.